# Pretty slick - Pretty sly and clever?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "pretty slick" mean "(Republicans are) very sly and clever"?

Oxford Dictionaries: slick
​(sometimes disapproving) done or made in a way that is clever and efficient but often does not seem to be sincere or lacks important ideas
a slick advertising campaign
a slick performance
You had to admire the slick

> (An American citizen wrote online:)
> Biden doesn't even have enough support among the Democrats to repeal the f***ing filibuster. The Democrats don't have enough support in the country to elect sixty senators. And in red states where the Republicans might be vulnerable they simply make it difficult for Democrats to vote, and give their state governments the power to overturn elections which don't go their way. Pretty slick.

Comment: Have you looked up _slick_ in the dictionary?

Comment: Of course I did. I've edited the OP.    The problem is who's the target of the comment "Pretty slick."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author means "these tactics (that Republicans use) are pretty "sly and clever".  "Slick" describes the actions, and by implication the people who are performing the actions.